# Trying to get add something to an Listview when I press a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working to figure out data binding and item sources with WPF and C#, and I'm missing something when it comes to making the proper binding connections.  The result is a runtime error:

`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=SettingsWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=teams; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`

The code itself is pretty straightforward (I think):

SettingsWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Bridge.SettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Settings" Height="480" Width="600">
    ...
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Add Team" Click="ClickAddTeam"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding team.color}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
    ...

</Window>
```

SettingsWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class SettingsWindow : Window
{
    public TeamList teams { get; set; }

    public SettingsWindow()
    {
        teams = TeamManager.Instance().teamList; // persists in a different class
        this.DataContext = this.teams;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClickAddTeam(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TeamManager manager = TeamManager.Instance();
        Team toAdd = manager.GetSampleTeam(teams.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(toAdd.ToString());

        teams.Add(toAdd);

        if(teams.Count == manager.sampleTeams.Count)
            (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Team.cs:

```
namespace DataTypes
{
    public class Team
    {
        public string name;
        public Brush color;

        public Team(string name, Brush color)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now working:**

<s>The WriteLine in ClickAddTeam is printing the right data, so I know it's retrieving the Team object correctly *and* that the `MyTeamList teams` object is getting stuff added to it.  The button is also being disabled after the appropriate number of clicks.  The ListBox, however, stays empty the entire time.</s>

**Next step:**
I'm trying to get the strings in the ListBox to be *team*.name rather than "DataTypes.Team", and for the text's foreground to be the team's color.  How do I grab a specific property of the bound element?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So did you set a data context?  this.DataContext = this;  Is SettingsWindow defined?

Comment: I assumed that `ElementName=SettingsWindow` would point to the code-behind class by the same name; is that not the case?  In any case, I got something working, but it displays "DataTypes.Team" instead of any kind of string.  How might I populate the Listbox with objects, but specify the string for it to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding only works with **public properties**. Try to declare `teams` as property instead of field/member:

```
public MyTeamList teams { get; set; }
```

// OP note: This part below wouldn't compile, giving me a `member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type` error.

and because you're binding by `ElementName`, you need to name you `Window` properly :

```
<Window x:Class="Bridge.SettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="SettingsWindow"
        Title="Settings" Height="480" Width="600">
```

[OP Note]

Just changing that line to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` works for displaying stuff, but every item displays as "DataType.Team" instead of a proper string.  That's the next thing to figure out.

[/OP Note]

Comment: I'm getting this error now: `'SettingsWindow': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`, which I'm guessing has something to do with the x:Name tag?  The `{Binding ElementName=SettingsWindow, Path=teams}` part, I pieced together from other examples, but I'm not entirely sure what it's doing.  Is that the best/proper way to access an ItemsSource in the code-behind?  I ask because you said "because you're binding by" as though there's a more common alternative.  Thanks!

Comment: Scratch that, I got something working and persisting.  Next step is to display a string from the object rather than the "DataTypes.Team" that it currently is.  I'll edit your answer to include all the necessary info.

Comment: you should've edited your question instead of answer. Anyway, to fix the latest problem, try to set `DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName"` in ListView. PropertyName is property of `Team` you want to display.

Comment: I just updated the question with the next step, too.  I edited your answer since it took both part of your fix and @Blam's fix to get it to work; neither was complete on its own.  I'm still kinda new to SO, so apologies if that's a faux pas here.  It looks like that will work for the text, but not changing the color of the text according to a property of a `Team`.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be one question per question

You need to set the DataContext
this.DataContext = this;

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TeamList}"  DisplayMemberPath=Name

And name needs to be a public property (get)